# Fillezilla RSA Public key Storage

Tags: rsa, sftp, public-key, filezilla

Quick question about RSA Public Key. I know putty stores Publick key in Reg (HCU-Software-SimonTaTham-SSHHostKey) but does someone know were Filezilla strore it? I need to delete it.